# Oracle Dll Load error: unable to run C# console applicatin on a different machine

Tags: c#, oracle, dll

I have developed a C# console application(.NET 4.5.2) on my Windows

8.1(64 bit machine).
I used Visual Studio 2015(the only available option as we don't have 
licenses for newer)

I need to access Oracle (11G) database for my application.

My requirement is that  my application should run on a **clean 
machine**,means no Oracle client installed and 
a DLL should be enough to access the database(like we do with Java

JDBC jars)

As I already mention I developed and built my app on Windows 8.1 (64

bit) with x64 in the visual studio 2015 build config

I used Oracle.DataAccess for DB access and I simply added Oracle.Web

also in the references.
Everything works properly on my machine.

Now when I try to run the built application(exe with all the dlls in

the same folder) on a windows Vista(64 bit machine)
I get the following error.

**D:\distribution_C#_x64>EAS_Background_Alert.exe
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type 
initializer fo
r 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. 
---> System.Dl
lNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified 
module coul
d not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsInit.CheckVersionCompatibility
(String version)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---**

I have the following dlls in the folder
1. oci.dll
2. ociw32.dll
3. Oracle.DataAccess.dll
4. Oracle.Web.dll
5. oramts.dll
6. oramts12.dll
7. oramtsus.dll
8. orannzsbb12.dll
9. oraocci12.dll
10. oraociei12.dll
11. oraons.dll
12. OraOps12.dll

I copied these DLLs from the ODAC(oracle data access client folders

intalled on my machine)

Can Anyone help?

[Note: Just thought to mention , my application generates pdf reports

and I also have itextsharp.dll in the folder(and it works fine on my

machine)]

Also, today I tried to run it on Windows Vista, tomorrow it can be

Windows 7.
So, how can I make sure  that a built application runs properly on

all machines.

Comment: In case it helps, I have been a Java developer traditionally

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not install the Oracle Instant [client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) (or any [other](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) version of Oracle Client). This is a prerequisite.

Here's another [link](https://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/utilsoft-086879.html)

Download, unzip, then ref it in your project (Copy Local: True)